# ActiveRecord is not updating data

Tags: yii

Here is a piece of my code

```
$file=Files::model()->findByPk($id);   
if($file == null) {
     throw new CHttpException(404,'Not found');   
}
$count = $file->count;           
$count++;                             
$file->count = $count;           
$file->save();                                      
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->hostInfo."/".$file->path);
```

The `Files` model contains a `count` field.
The code is ok, and there are no warnings, but the save method is not working.

Comment: try `$file->getErrors()` to display after save() and before redirect to see if there are no errors

Comment: Thanks! In database one field was empty but in rules it was requred, and i get an error!

Comment: then mark it as an answer so if anyone fells in problem he or she knows what to do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `$file->getErrors()` to display after save() and before redirect to see if there are no errors

this would show you what is the problem. Most common is you are not populating the dependencies required for a model to insert a row in database

to see it in well format use

```
CVarDumper::Dump($file->getErrors(),100,true)
```